# how to get specific initial dice movement in snakes and ladder

Tags: java, javafx

Any help shall be much appreciated!

I'm new to java and need to make java app(snakes and ladder) for college project but got stuck.

I'm facing problem with the dice movements I have done the coding but it gives random number and the problem is :

I have been to told that the game should only start if the dice value is 1 or 6.
So how do I predefine it so that my dice's initial value is 1 or 6?

2nd problem if a player's dice value is 6 he should get another chance.

code:

```
if(togglePlayer==1){
    turnIndicator.setText("Player A's turn");
    togglePlayer=0; // using togglePlayer to switch between players

    if(cheatInjector==0){
                face=1;    
                cheatInjector=1;
    }                                                                                                                                                                
    else{face=r.nextInt(6);

    }
    switch (face)
    {

        case 0:
            rollDice1(primaryStage);
            face = 1;

            break;
        case 2:
            rollDice2(primaryStage);
            face = 2;
            break;
        case 3:
            rollDice3(primaryStage);
            face = 3;
            break;
        case 4:
            rollDice4(primaryStage);
            face = 4;
            break;
        case 5:
            rollDice5(primaryStage);
            face = 5;
            break;
        case 6:
            rollDice6(primaryStage);
            face = 6;

            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have been to told that the game should only start if the dice value
>   is 1 or 6. So how do I predefine it so that my dice's initial value is
>   1 or 6?

Two separate questions here.

To start the game if your dice roll is 1 or 6, should be something like the following:

```
int diceRoll = rollDice();
if (diceRoll == 1 || diceRoll == 6) {
    // start game
}
```

To *predefine* your dice roll, simply:

```
int diceRoll = 1; 
// or
int diceRoll = 6;
```

> 2nd problem if a player's dice value is 6 he should get another
>   chance.

You didn't really ask a question here, but if you always want to roll again when it's 6, you could do something like this:

```
int diceRoll = 0;
do {
    diceRoll = rollDice();
} while (diceRoll == 6);
```

But there are many other ways you could implement it.

Just giving you somewhere to start rather than doing your homework.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int rollDice(int repeat) {
    System.out.println("ROLLING DICE...PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE:");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String cont = in.nextLine();
    int rolledNo = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    if (rolledNo == 6) {
        System.out.println("NUMBER IS:" + rolledNo + ". ANOTHER CHANCE.");
        rollDice(repeat++);
    } else {
        System.out.println("NUMBER IS:" + rolledNo);
    }
    int finalCount = rolledNo + (repeat * 6);
    return finalCount;
}
```